# How to prepare PHP variable for Javascript array() use?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, filter, sanitization

Let's say that we have input field or textarea where user can put anything. This means that user can put there:

- text
- white spaces
- multilines
- HTML tags
- single and double quotes
- slashes
- and whatnot...

My current code does this: `<?php $data = addslashes($content_of_input); ?>`

and soon after that...

```
<?php
    $php_generate_javascriptArray .='
        javascriptArray[0] ="'.$data.'";
    ';
?>
<script>
    javascriptArray = [];
    <?php echo $php_generate_javascriptArray; ?>
</script>
```

Adding slashes unfortunately isn't enough - Javascript breaks when user puts for instance multiple lines or HTML links into that. Is there any way to prevent that and still **ALLOW Javascript array to contain LINK, MULTIPLE LINES, HTML TAGS**? I'm looking for some universal filters.

Answer (score 6):

[`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) will convert a PHP data structure (or string, or number) to the appropriate JavaScript data structure while making it safe for injecting into a script element in an HTML document (by escaping slashes).

```
<script>
    var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?> ;
</script>
```

Comment: For some reason - in the above example - adding `json_encode()` instead of `addslashes()` breaks Javascript altogether even when using plain text. Perhaps because I'm using double quotes?

Comment: @Paul — Yes, `json_encode` will output a literal (string, array, object, etc). You need to output it directly and not wrap it in quotes (which it might contain) to make it a string.

Comment: I need to use PHP `for()` to generate very, very long multi-dimensional Javascript `array()`. The above example is my only choice. In my question I simplified it. Is there any way to do it using my above example?

Comment: Use `for()` to generate a very long multi-dimensional **PHP** array. Then json_encode it.

Comment: EDIT: Okay, I tested and it so far it is okay.

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP function [urlencode(...)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)
or [base64_encode(...)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) of need of more advanced protection.

I normal use urlencode and on Javascript side use unescape for decode the URL format data.